# can't add a row to database

Tags: php, mysqli

i have just written a simple code to insert a row to my database called profiles but it doesn't work .

code:

```
<?php   
      $mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", "****", "****", "****");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the database. Error number: " . $this->mysqli->connect_errno);
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO 'profiles' VALUES ( aaa , aaa , aaa , aaa , aaa , aaa , 1 , 1 , 0 , aaa , 0 )");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows <= 0){
            throw new Exception("Unable to add record in the database! Query returned: " . $result);
    }
    echo "1";
?>
```

my database :

```
1   username    varchar(20) 
2   password    varchar(200)    
3   email   varchar(20) 
4   name    varchar(20) 
5   city    varchar(200)    
6   address varchar(200)    
7   mf  varchar(5)  
8   pp  varchar(5)  
9   reputation  varchar(20) 
10  register_date   varchar(20)
11  kh_f varchar(5)
```

and the error log:

```
[18-Jul-2014 12:32:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to add record in the database! Query returned: ' in /home/***/***/***/**/test.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/***/***/***/**/test.php on line 9
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: Use mysqli_error() to get the error message mysql is reporting. Also , catch your exceptions.

Comment: You have quotes where you shouldn't be using, and quotes where you should be using them but you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `mysqli_error()` to get your error ;)

And add quote to your strings : `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO profiles VALUES ( 'aaa' , 'aaa' , 'aaa' , 'aaa' , 'aaa' , 'aaa' , '1' , '1' , '0' , 'aaa' , '0' )");`

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO 'profiles' VALUES ..."
```

NOT `'profiles'` but `profiles` with button that is located on the left side of `1(!)` i can't write this sign because bbcode parse it as code